# How do I bring changes from the Chef Server into my local repository?

Tags: chef-infra

So we're setting up Chef on the Opscode platform for the first time to manage a significant cluster deployment.  We have the client set up, the development environment with a full chef-repo checked into Git, etc. Knife works great for *uploading* things from the repo into the server.

The Chef management console is sort of nice.  It lets you edit almost anything online.  But therein lies the problem: we've made changes online, and can't figure out how to *download* them back down into the local repository so that they can be checked into source control.

Is there a knife command we're missing?  Or any other repeatable way to do this, short of writing a script to list each role and environment and pipe them into files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for this, but there is a backup plugin in this repo:

https://github.com/stevendanna/knife-hacks

which I've used to dump our server into our repository.

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to check out this post. I was facing a similar problem.

[download roles and cookbooks from ChefServer with knife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756347/download-roles-and-cookbooks-from-chefserver-with-knife/10859137#10859137)

Answer (score 0):

[`knife download [PATTERN...] (options)`](http://docs.chef.io/client/knife_download.html)

Examples are all taken from the doc page to which I linked above.

Download the entire chef repo:

`knife download /`

Download cookbooks (directory):

`knife download cookbooks`

Download environments (directory):

`knife download environments`