# download roles and cookbooks from ChefServer with knife

Tags: chef-infra, continuous-deployment

Given I started working with Chef using the Chef Server Management Console and I now want to start using a files and upload them via knife. 
Is there a way to retrive roles and environments that are stored on the ChefServer via knife, so I can them into git?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `knife environment list` and `knife environment show` commands to download environments and replace "environment" with "role" to do the same for roles.

```
mkdir environments
for env in `knife environment list`; do
  knife environment show $env --format=json > environments/$env.json
done
```

You can then check these JSON files into git and edit/upload with knife.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned cookbooks in your title, but not your post.

if you want to download cookbooks, `knife cookbook download NAME` works. Put it in a for loop like Tim Potter did and you get all your cookbooks.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You're correct, but the cookbooks were already on the filesystem and we've been using knife to upload them to the server.